# Creating a loop that has a one second gap between loops [Handling Exceptions in the code]

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jlabel, sleep

I'm trying to create a countdown timer that will update a `Jlabel` in Java for a quiz app. So far I have this for my code but it gives an error for the `sleep()` method and doesn't run my program.

```java
while (timer > 0) {
     lblTimer.setText(Integer.toString(timer));
     Thread.sleep(1000);
     timer--;
}
```

Comment: `it gives an error` - what error?

Comment: Are you running this code on the main thread?

Comment: Thread.sleep() can  throw only `InterruptedException`

Comment: Thats exactly what it says when i add it. Interrupter Exception

Comment: 'Unhandled exception type InterruptedException'

Comment: @AStephens please edit your question and add more code, whole method, not just this small part

Comment: @AStephens It means that `Thread.sleep()` can throw `InterruptedException` and you need to handle it in your code, either by catching it and handle it in your catch or throw it in your method. There should be tons of examples on how to handle this the best way.

Comment: It's not a good idea to sleep the main thread for the sake of responsiveness.

Comment: Use a `Swing` based `Timer` to both do this the correct way and get around the need to use `Thread.sleep(..)` (which should definitely ***not*** be used in a GUI).

Answer (score 1):

```
class JlabelUpdater {
   private JLabel label;
   private Integer timerTickCount;
   private Integer tickerIntervalInMillis;
   private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = 
           Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

   public JlabelUpdater(JLabel label, Integer timerTickCount, 
                        Integer tickerIntervalInMillis) {
      this.label = label;
      this.timerTickCount = timerTickCount;
      this.tickerIntervalInMillis = tickerIntervalInMillis;
   }

   public void startTimer() {
     scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
        if (timerTickCount == 0) {
           scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
        }

        System.out.println("timer running: " + timerTickCount);
          changeText(timerTickCount + "");
          timerTickCount--;
         }, 0, tickerIntervalInMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
   }

   private void changeText(final String text) {
      EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
             label.setText(text);
             System.out.println("text = " + text);
         }
      );
   }
}
```

If you want a timer for 5 seconds and update the `JLabel` text every 1 second you can create an object of this class and call it like this.

```
new JlabelUpdater(new JLabel(), 5, 1000).startTimer();
```

It is always recommended to use `ScheduledExecutorService` instead of `Timer`
whenever possible.

Comment: Surely there is a simpler way of just having a label that within a loop waits 1 second and the changes the value in the label?

Comment: simple is totally contextual, 3 lines of code may look simple with different levels of complexity. In a concurrent world thread is not a simple thing. To point out a few, you shouldn't sleep main/UI thread which is involved in user interaction and you can't update UI element from background/worker thread as UI elements are main thread confined. This list goes on...

Answer (score 0):

Add a try catch block to catch the exception

```
     while (timer > 0) {
            lblTimer.setText(Integer.toString(timer));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            timer--;

           }
```

Comment: When I try that the program doesn't load at all.